# General Question about a GUI to execute a batch file

Tags: user-interface

I'm new to programming and have taken some classes in it so I'm not sure if this is possible.  I want to use a COTS software called 010 Hex Editor and write a script for the program to automate a couple tasks.  These tasks can be run from a batch file according to their documentation.

Then I want to instruct the user to eject the device and reinsert it to clear the cache.  (This I want done just with a simple pop-up window.

Then I also want to format the device which I assume can be done in a batch file as it can be done through dos on Windows.

My question is, with these 3 steps, can I build a simple GUI that has a button that says, "Start" or something like that, then the pop up window comes up to eject and reinsert, and then another button to format, and another button to exit.  I'm not really familiar with what language this could be done in, and how to do this as the C++/Java classes I've taken have been more about syntax and OOP.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the windows messenger service to put up an alert - but on newer windows (vista/7) it's a pain to set all the permissions to allow this.

There are lots of free utilities that will popup a dialog from the command line, with a given message and wait for a response.

They are generally called messagebox or msgbox - sorry can't recommend any in particular